# How to specify a columns dtype by its index rather than its name in pandas pd.read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to read data from Excel but while doing it I should not specify the columns by their names. How can I set data types using indexing?

For instance:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', 
                 sheet_name='sheet1',
                 index_col=None, 
                 dtype={'column_x':str, 'column_y':str}, engine='openpyxl')
```

here, instead of stating `"column_x"` and `"column_y"`, can I reach them with something like:

```
dtype={df.colums[0]:str, df.colums[1]:str}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you can use df.iloc[:, 0] for column 0 and df.iloc[:, 1] for column 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `header=None` then access the columns by their index position.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2,3], 'B' : ['A','B','C','A']})

print(df.dtypes)

A     int64
B    object
dtype: object


df.to_excel('file.xlsx'index=False)
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',index_col=None)
print(df.dtypes)

A     int64
B    object
dtype: object

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',index_col=None,
       header=None,dtype={0 : 'str', 1 : 'str'},skiprows=1) 
       # skip the header row otherwise all cols will be read as strings.

print(df.dtypes)

0    object
1    object
dtype: object
```

note, you'll need to set your columns manually after this.